# url of the controller method on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a button for Adding data and another button for editing data. On clicking the `Add` button I am getting the correct `url` but `edit` button is not working as expected.

```
// Add button
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom:10px;" onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddorEdit", "Vehicles")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add New</a>
```

On inspecting this button, I get `onclick="PopupForm('/Vehicles/AddorEdit')"`

complete js code for the edit button,

var Popup, dataTable;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    dataTable = $("#tbl_vehicle").DataTable({

        "ajax":{
            "url": "/Vehicles/GetVehicle",
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "VehicleType" },
            { "data": "Amount" },
            { "data": "RenewPeriod" },
            { "data": "RegisteredDate",
                "render": function(data)
                {
                    var date = moment(data).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
                    return date;
                }
            },
            { "data": "RegisteredBy" },
            { "data": "Status",
                    "render" : function(data)
                {
                    if(data === "1") return "Active"
                    else return "Passive"
                }
            },
            { "data": "ModifiedBy" },
            { "data": "ModifiedDate" },
            {
                "data": "Id",
                "render": function(data)
                {
                    var myUrl = "Vehicles/AddorEdit/" + data;

                    var result= "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' onclick='PopupForm(" + myUrl + ")'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete </a>"
                    console.log(result);
                    return result;

                },
                "width": "150px"
            }
        ],
        "language": {
            "emptyTable" : "No data available, please click on <b>Add</b> button"
        }

    });

});
```

On inspecting this button, I am getting `onclick="PopupForm(/Vehicles/AddorEdit/28)"`, there is no `'` in the parameter. On clicking this edit button, the pop up form is also not opening.

javascript code for `PopupForm` and `SubmitForm`

```
function PopupForm(url) {
            var formDiv = $('<div/>');
            $.get(url).done(function (response) {
                formDiv.html(response);

                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: false,
                    title: 'fill details',
                    height: 500,
                    width: 700,
                    close: function () {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }
                });
            });
        }

        function SubmitForm(form) {
            //console.log($(form).serialize());
            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "/Vehicles/AddorEdit",  //form.action,
                data: $(form).serialize(),

                success: function (data) {
                    if(data.success)
                    {
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        //dataTable.DataTable(ajax.reload());
                        $("#tbl_vehicle").DataTable().ajax.reload();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you cannot pass a client-side value to this `@Url.Action()` as a parameter since The `@Url.Action()` method is processed on the server-side. You can concat the client-side variables with the server-side url generated by this method, which is a string on the output. Try something like this:

```
var myUrl = '@Url.Action("AddorEdit","Vehicles")?data=' + data;
```

Since you are using `DataTables`, you can do something like:

```
{
    "data": "Id",
    "render": function (data) {

        var link ='@Url.Action("AddorEdit", "Vehicles", new { id = "data" })';
        link = link.replace("data", data);
        var result = "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' onclick=\"PopupForm('"+link+"')\"><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete </a>"                                   
        return result;

    },
    "width": "150px"
}
```

Comment: I am facing problem in `PopupForm` parameter. Whatever I keep in var myUrl, its not properly formatted in onclick event. Please check my comments in other reply. Thank You!!!

Comment: @nischalinn Why not just return the string like: `return "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' onclick='PopupForm("@Url.Action("AddorEdit","Vehicles")?data=' + data'")'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete </a>"`

Comment: When I kept your code, even `DataTable` is not populated.

Comment: @nischalinn Remove the extra `'`: `?data=' + data"`

Comment: @nischalinn Also can you show us the entire code on how you are rendering your button?

Comment: from your last edited code I am getting `onclick="PopupForm("" +myurl+'")' ="" ` . Even not retrieving the value of `myurl` variable.

Comment: No, it is not working.... Please see my above comment. Thank You!!!

Comment: @nischalinn What problem are you encountering now?

Comment: still same problem... url is not fetched properly.

Comment: @nischalinn Can you show me your `PopupForm` function? The `link` variable is properly being generated and being sent to my dummy function that I created.

Comment: @nischalinn Please find updated code. Change this line only: `var result = "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' onclick=\"PopupForm('"+link+"')\"><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete </a>"`

Comment: @nischalinn Glad to help. If my answer helped you out, please click on the tick mark to accept the answer and do not forget to up-vote so others can see the correct answer

Answer (score 2):

You should concat the `'` correct way

```
return "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' onclick='PopupForm('"+myUrl+"')'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete </a>"
```

Check my sample below:

```js
var myUrl = "/Vehicles/AddorEdit" + 28;
var result = "<a class='btn btn-warning btn-sm' onclick='PopupForm('"+myUrl+"')'><i class='fa fa-edit'></i> Edit </a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px;'><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Delete </a>";
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? Let me know if you need any help @nischalinn

Comment: I tried your code but it's not working. Here's what I get on `inspecting element` by putting your code `<a class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="PopupForm(" addoredit="" vehicles28')'=""><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> Edit </a>`

Comment: Did you see my sample? It's already given us expected `'`. You should check your 'myurl' value then concat `'` like a advise you before.

Comment: Yes `console.log(result)` is showing the required correct result but when I return the same value `result` and do inspect element on Edit button it is showing `onclick="PopupForm(" vehicles="" addoredit="" 25')'=""`
both in mozilla firefox as well as chrome. Why is it so ? I think thats why my pop up form is not opening on Edit button click.